# CryptoPP Library to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, aes

I am trying to use CryptoPP Library with Visual Stuio for AES Encryption

But I am taking some errors,

I am using C++ Language, but I am quitely new at C++

Here is my main code;

```
#include "C:\Users\Window\Desktop\cryptopp562\osrng.h"
using CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool;

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;

#include "C:\Users\Window\Desktop\cryptopp562\cryptlib.h"
using CryptoPP::Exception;

#include "C:\Users\Window\Desktop\cryptopp562\hex.h"
using CryptoPP::HexDecoder;
using CryptoPP::HexEncoder;

#include "C:\Users\Window\Desktop\cryptopp562\filters.h"
using CryptoPP::StringSink;
using CryptoPP::StreamTransformation;
using CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter;

#include "C:\Users\Window\Desktop\cryptopp562\aes.h"
using CryptoPP::AES;

#include "C:\Users\Window\Desktop\cryptopp562\modes.h"
using CryptoPP::ECB_Mode;

int main() {
    AutoSeededRandomPool aSRP;
    byte key[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
    aSRP.GenerateBlock(key, sizeof(key));

    string plainText = "", encoded, decoded, cipher;

    CryptoPP::StringSource(key, sizeof(key), true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(encoded)));

    std::cout << "Key --> " << encoded << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Plain Text --> " << plainText << std::endl;

    ECB_Mode <AES>::Encryption e;

    e.SetKey(key, sizeof(key));

    CryptoPP::StringSource(plainText, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(e, new StringSink(cipher)));

    std::cout << "Cipher --> " << cipher << std::endl;

    //decryption
    ECB_Mode<AES>::Decryption d;
    std::string recoverdCipher = "";

    d.SetKey(key, sizeof(key));

    CryptoPP::StringSource(plainText, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(e, new StringSink(recoverdCipher)));

    return 1;
}
```

Here are the problems;

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning LNK4098 defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    AES C:\Users\Window\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AES\AES\LINK  1

Thanks in advance

Comment: And did you try to apply `/NODEFAULTLIB:library AES` in your project linker settings as the error message suggests?

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the code you posted.  The error is a linker error, not a compiler error.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how can I that ? I added the library link to the linker as C:\Users\Window\Desktop\cryptopp562\Win32\Output\Debug\cryptlib.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So, what should I do to solve this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: @NewPHPer I think there should be something like miscellaneous _linker flags_, search through linker options in the project settings